# Overwrite first element in C array

Tags: c++, arrays

The code below works:

```
uint8_t test[2] = "7";
cout << test[0];
```

but if I afterwards add the following code so that I change "7" to "5" then it won't work:

```
test[0] = "5";
cout << test[0];
```

I get the error:

error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to uint8_t

Why is that?

Comment: `"5"` is string. `'5'` is 5.

Comment: You cannot assign `"5"` to `test[0]`. `test[0]` is of type `char` (or `char&`) but `"5"` is of type `const char[2]`. Please, try `'5'` instead.

Comment: If you wonder that it worked in `uint8_t test[2] = "7";` - that's something different. In this case, `=` represented an initialization (in the other case an assignment of element).

Comment: Be aware that on *declaration*, the number within `[]` is *not* an index, but size of array. *Later on*, it is the index. So depending on the context `[]` has different meaning...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"7"` is a string literal. Strings are arrays of characters, and so are string literals. The string literals can be used to initialise other arrays of characters. `uint8_t` doesn't look like a character type, but it is actually an alias to `unsigned char`. As such, `uint8_t test[2]` is an array of characters, and it can be initialised using a string literal.

`test[0]` is not an array of characters. It is a single character (in particular, it is the first character within the array `test`). It is not possible to assign a string literal to a character. It is however possible to assign a character literal to a character, which you may have intended in this case:

```
test[0] = '5';
```

---

P.S. `test = "5"` would not work either. Arrays can be initialised, but they cannot be assigned.

Comment: `uint8_t` is not necessarily an alias for `unsigned char`.   It does, in practice, often work out that way, but it is not required by the standard.   In more general terms, `uint8_t` and `unsigned char` are both unsigned integral types and can be converted to each other.

Comment: @Peter `unsigned char` must have at least eight bits with no padding.  If `uint8_t` exists, then it must have exactly eight bits with no padding, and it must be at least as large as `unsigned char`.  Hence if `uint8_t` exists, it and `unsigned char` must both be exactly eight bits with no padding.  A compiler could define a type which has the same representation as `unsigned char`, but is a different type (just as `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three different types but `char` must have the same representation as one of the others), but I don't believe any extant compiler does.

Comment: @Peter No.  `uint8_t` is not required to be two-complement - it is required to be unsigned.  I think the only possible variation in representation is that they could have different bit numberings.  (So eg bit 0 (the lsb) of a `uint8_t` is bit 4 of an `unsigned char`.  It's not forbidden, but for practical engineering purposes, it won't happen.)

Answer (score 1):

On initialisation you're saying

```
uint8_t test[2] = "7";
```

Through using "", you're telling the program to store a string literal, and so `test[0]`, the first element of your array, stores `7` and the `test[1]`, the second element of your array, stores `\0` which is a null-terminator. A null terminator simply tells your array that there is no more characters which are part of this array beyond this point - even though there could be IF there was still memory spaces assigned to the array available (in this case there isn't - the array has only two spaces as defined by the two in its declaration).

Now,

```
test[0] = "5";
```

You're telling to store `5` AND `\0` in a `uint8_t`. It isn't possible. If you want to store just the character 5, and not a char array type string, you need to say

```
test[0] = '5';
```

After setting `test[0]` to 5 just as above, your array `test` would contain a literal string "5", since `\0` is still present at `test[1]`, due to your previous initialisation.

Note also that you don't need to specify the size of your array as 2 at initialisation. It will automatically assign itself the minimum size to store the string literal with the brackets left blank, which would still be 2 (`7` and `\0`), as shown below:

```
uint8_t test[] = "7";
```

Comment: For an array `uint8_t test[2]`, there is no _memory space at `test[2]`_ which you can rely on. Accessing `test[2]` in array `uint8_t test[2]` is out of bound access i.e. Undefined Behavior.

Comment: *But* `&test[2]` (or simply `test + 2`) is a valid address. It's the one past the end pointer, so you can use it for pointer arithmetics, but you cannot dereference it (as @Scheff already pointed out).

Comment: @Scheff True, I got muddled up. Hopefully correct now.

Comment: I saw. I considered to delete my comment but I found the `&test[2]` comment of Aconcagua remarkable and left mine as it somehow built upon mine. ;-)

Comment: You could add something to the already nice answer of Eeroika (worth to be voted), if you would mention `uint8_t test[] = "7";` as an alternative definition (which might be even better in certain cases).

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to put a string in at place where `test[0]` is pointing.

`"5"` is actually the character `'5'` and `'\0'` ("5/0").
If you want to place a character there do it like this.

```
test[0] = '5';
```